# How much calcium hydroxide is needed to raise the pH of an aqueous sulphuric acid solution?

Tags: acid-base, ph, concentration

Lets say dissociation constants $K_{\mathrm{a}1}$ & $K_{\mathrm{a}2}$ of $\ce{H_2SO_4}$ in water are $1000$ and $0.012$ respectively. So the first dissociation step happens completely:
$$\ce{ H_2SO_4 (l) + H_2O (l) \rightleftharpoons HSO_4^- (aq) + H_3O^+(aq)}$$
Where: $\ce{[HSO_4^-] = [H_2SO_4]_0)}$, let those be $c_0$. And the second step:
$$\ce{ HSO_4^-(aq) + H_2O(l) \rightleftharpoons SO_4^{2-}(aq) + H_3O^+(aq)}$$
So the IE table for the second step would look something like this:

|  | $\ce{[HSO_4^-]}$ | $\ce{[SO_4^{2-}]}$ | $\ce{[H_3O^+]}$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Initial | $c_0$ | 0 | $c_0$ |
| Equilibrium | $c_0(1-\alpha)$ | $c_0\alpha$ | $c_0(1+\alpha)$ |

So at equilibrium, $K_{\mathrm{a2}} = \frac{[\ce{SO_4^{2-}][H_3O^+][HSO_4^-]}} {(1 - \alpha)} = \frac{c_0\alpha(1+\alpha)}{(1-\alpha)}$. Which can be solved for $\alpha$: $c_0\alpha^2+(c_0+K_{\mathrm{a2}})\alpha-K_{\mathrm{a2}}=0$

Then, $\alpha$ can be used to obtain the $p$H of the solution at equilibrium:

$p$H = - $log\ce{[H_3O^+]}$)= - $log$ $ { \pu{c_o( 1+\alpha)}}$)

So, if this solution is to be neutralized with $\ce{Ca(OH)_2}$ to a certain pH, lets say $11$, how would I calculate the amount of lime needed to increase the $p$H by that much?

Thank for your time

Comment: Why choosing $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ and not $\ce{NaOH}$? Neutralization sulfuric acid with $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ produces $\ce{CaSO4}$, which is not very soluble in water ($0.0047$ M, from solubility product). And measured solubility is much higher : $0.018$ M (Journal of Chemical Education 77, 12, Dec. 2000, p. 1558). This is due to other ions like $\ce{[Ca(OH)]^+}$ and  $\ce{HSO4^-}$.

Comment: Please have a look at the mhchem extension of MathJax for correct typography.

Comment: If you wanted pH = 11 then acid would be irrelevant and the basic properties of hydroxide would be needed for calculation.